# Embed settings.xml into ivy.xml

Tags: java, ant, ivy

I understand that it's completely wrong and is not a good practice, but I need to know if it is possible to somehow embed fragment of ivysettings.xml into ivy.xml or Apache Ant build.xml and use it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<target name="resolve-init" description="Configure ivy settings">
    <mkdir dir="build"/>

    <echoxml file="build/ivysettings.xml">
        <ivysettings>
            <settings defaultResolver="central" />
            <resolvers>
                <ibiblio name="central" m2compatible="true"/>
            </resolvers>
        </ivysettings>
    </echoxml>

    <ivy:settings file="build/ivysettings.xml"/>
</target>

<target name="resolve" depends="resolve-init" description="Use ivy to resolve dependencies">
    <ivy:resolve/>
</target>
```

The other option is to use the URL attribute of the ivy settings task to save the ivy configuration in a well known location, for example a company web server.